# How to search JSON data in mysql using Regular expression

Tags: mysql, json, regex, expression, strongloop

I am new to regular expression, I have stored JSON data in table. I want to fetch data based on userId, userId is a property of  Users Object.

Example: I want fetch all the records if users contain 513

My table data sample:

```
 Table name:share

Id  name            sharedusers
1   xxxx            {"accessType":0,"permission":"1","specificUsers":
                    [{"users":"502,512,513","permission":"1"}]}

2   yyy             {"accessType":0,"permission":"1","specificUsers":
                    [{"users":"47,52,60","permission":"1"}]} 

3   zzzz            {"accessType":0,"permission":"1","specificUsers":
                    [{"users":"502,512,513","permission":"1"}]}
```

> I have tried this code  but I am getting all the records, filter is not applied

```
SELECT * FROM share where sharedusers  REGEXP '"users":"[[:<:]]513[[:>:]]"';
```

Please give any sample.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
REGEXP '"users":"[^"]*[[:<:]]513[[:>:]]'
```

Here, `[^"]*` (0+ characters other than `"`) is added and final `"` is removed to effectively match `513` as a whole word inside a pair of quotes that enclose the value.

Comment: how to convert this ( '"users":"[^"]*[[:<:]]513[[:>:]]' )RegEx to                                                 String defining a regular expression (for example, '^foo' ).
Regular expression literal (for example, /^foo/ ).
Regular expression object (for example, new RegExp(/John/)).

Comment: if you need more details please look this link https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Where+filter#Wherefilter-Regularexpressions

Comment: You mean you need a JavaScript compatible regex? Use `/"users":"[^"]*\b513\b/`

Comment: @Thanks for your response. I tried in node.js but still I am getting error. can you give same(/"users":"[^"]*\b513\b/) in string defining format?

Comment: I tried in javascriipt but I am getting undefined.                                                           var patt = new RegExp(/"users":"[^"]*\b513\b/);
var json= {"accessType":0,"permission":"1","specificUsers":
                    [{" users":"502,512,513","permission":"1"}]};
var res = patt.json;

Comment: `RegExp` does not have any property called json. See [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/69m7wf75/), hope it will help.

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to fix, if I have any doubt I will ask you.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade to MySQL 5.7 and use the builtin functions for interrogating JSON columns.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will try.

Comment: Though, those functions don't include regex support as far as I recall. Including mysql 8

Comment: @John - Use the Json functions _instead of_ trying parse with a `REGEXP`.

Comment: @RickJames It's not a real solution, JSON_SEARCH and similar are by magnitudes less  flexible than regular expressions. 
In my specific case I have hundreds of regex codes with complex content already existing, I can't switch.  So I have to treat the json as text and search it that way which likely introduces a few problems due to escaping etc.